# JOIN using filesort, subquery not using it

Tags: mysql, join, indexing, subquery, filesort

This query (JOIN):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Token
FROM ID
INNER JOIN Tokens ON ID.Token_ID = Tokens.Token_ID
WHERE ID.Type =  'org'
OR (
ID.Type =  'lemma'
AND Tokens.Value <3
)
ORDER BY ID.Token_ID
LIMIT 200
```

is using filesort. This query (SUBQUERY):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Token
FROM ID
WHERE TYPE =  'org'
OR (

TYPE =  'lemma'
AND Token_ID
IN (

SELECT Token_ID
FROM Tokens
WHERE Value <3
)
)
ORDER BY Token_ID
LIMIT 200
```

is not using filesort. I know JOIN should be faster then subquery, so I think I need some extra indexes: what indexes should I add in order not to use filesort in the join query?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slight variation on the query:

```
SELECT Token
FROM ID
WHERE TYPE =  'org'
UNION
SELECT Token
FROM ID
WHERE TYPE =  'lemma' AND
      EXISTS (SELECT t.Token_ID
              FROM Tokens t
              WHERE t.Token_ID = ID.Token_ID AND t.Value < 3
             )
ORDER BY Token
LIMIT 200;
```

The variation is that the `ORDER BY` uses `Token` rather than `Token_ID`.  The latter really doesn't make sense, and I'm surprised it doesn't generate an error.

For this query, you want in index on `ID(type, Token_Id, Token)` and `ID(Type, Token)` and `Tokens(Token_Id, Value)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The second query gives the same output as the first, but it's probably unclear: I need to check the value (< 3) only if the type is "lemma". Your query returns everything, because the EXISTS condition is always satisfied. The second query is in the "WHERE conditionA OR conditionB" form, which yes, can be translated in an equivalent query with an union instead of the OR. The second query is already efficient and doesn't use filesort, but my question is: can I do the same with the JOIN? I don't know what indexes should I add to use the JOIN query without the filesort.